# Variable not found error in Robot Framework

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, robotframework

I am new to RF and I encountered the 'Variable not found' error. 
I was trying to pass a user-defined variable under a user-defined keyword.

The code is as below

```
Decimal selection

[Arguments]      ${decimalval}

${decimalval} =   Set variable If
...               '${decimalval}'=='0'       //md-option[@value='0dp']
...               '${decimalval}'=='1'       //md-option[@value='1dp']  
...               '${decimalval}'=='2'       //md-option[@value='2dp']            

[return]          ${decimalval}
```

And once ${decimalval} is set with "//md-option[@value='#dp']" based on the condition, I try to use it under a user-defined keyword as below

```
Click Element       ${decimalval}
```

This is where the code fails and throws the variable not found error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Your keyword is setting the value and returning it. Is the code that is calling the keyword saving the return value? Please show an example test case that uses this keyword.

Comment: Hi Bryan, thanks very much. That helped! It is working now.

Answer (score 2):

Like Bryan mentioned in the comments, you are returning a value from the keyword. So there should be a variable to hold the return value while calling the keyword.

```
*** Test cases ***
Locator test
    ${decimalValueLocator}    Decimal selection    ${decimalval}
    Log to console    ${decimalValueLocator}
    Click element     ${decimalValueLocator}

*** Keywords ***
Decimal selection

    [Arguments]      ${decimalval}

    ${decimalval} =   Set variable If
    ...               '${decimalval}'=='0'       //md-option[@value='0dp']
    ...               '${decimalval}'=='1'       //md-option[@value='1dp']  
    ...               '${decimalval}'=='2'       //md-option[@value='2dp']            

    [return]          ${decimalval}
```

Comment: Hi Sameem, thanks for explaining it in detail. That helped. It is working now!